# iOS Persist a custom NSObject <MKAnnotation>

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, persistent-storage

I'm interested in persistent storage for a custom annotation object

`CustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>`

which has the following properties

`@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat val1;`
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *val2;`
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *val3;`
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *val4;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) double val5;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) double val6;`

What is the best approach to storing the data? I was thinking of using NSUserDefaults, but would I need to archive my CustomAnnotation into NSData? How do you do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to persist a custom object to `NSUserDefaults` you have two options.

1. Encode the object to NSData using an `NSKeyedArchiver`
2. Create an `NSDictionary` with all of the values you want to persist.

Whether using `NSUserDefaults` is the proper approach depends on a few factors. If you just have a one or a few of the objects then that would be fine. If you have a lot, then you may want to look at other options. Perhaps a plist or some other file. Either way, you have the same issue of needed to encode the object using one of the two approaches.